# Combination of several INDEX and MATCH functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I'm currently working on an evaluation excel sheet for forceplate data (showing vertical force development in jumps over time) and stumbled upon a problem that I couldn't manage to fix for the past days. Basically there are two main columns over ~ 4000 rows and 1 extra cell:

Column `A` shows time [in ms]

Column `B` shows vertical force measured at the time point in Column A

`C1` is the already calculated peak force value before takeoff

I am now trying to define the **timepoint of takeoff** in an extra cell using INDEX and MATCH functions (FYI: the time of takeoff is when the vertical force value is close to 0 for the first time [*range of lookup must be starting from the peak force value though!*!], but never exactly 0 due to force plate drift in measurement)

My idea was this:

```
=INDEX(A2:A4000;MATCH(0;INDEX(B2:B4000;MATCH(C1;B2:B4000;0)):B4000;-1))
```

so the range

```
INDEX(B2:B4000;MATCH(C1;B2:B4000;0)):B4000
```

should define a range of force values starting at the peak force value (`C1`).

Unfortunately Excel will show me a timepoint where the force value is far away from 0. I've tried the same formula within an easier (but for my purpose faulty) range (`B2:B4000`) and it worked perfectly, so I guess the problem I'm dealing with lies somewhere within the range defined with the INDEX function. 
I'd be glad if someone could help me out with this!

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly on the right track. It seems you've correctly adjusted the range in the nested [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) but that [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) will retunr the position within the adjusted B2:B4000. You need to adjust A2:A4000 in the same way so that the position returned by MATCH will be correct.

```
=INDEX(INDEX(A2:A4000; MATCH(C1; B2:B4000; 0)):A4000; MATCH(0; INDEX(B2:B4000; MATCH(C1; B2:B4000; 0)):B4000; -1))
```

I don't have sample data to test that on but I believe it is correct.